# Difference between spectrum and eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a continous compact self-adjoint endomorphism $T$ on a (complex) Hilbert space $H$. We can show that the set of non-zero eigenvalues and non-zero spectrum coincide and eigenvalues are in the spectrum. Is is possible that zero is spectrum whereas not an eigenvalue for such operator?

And why are we interested about the points outside the eigenvalues in the spectrum?

Comment: "And why are we interested about the points outside the eigenvalues in the spectrum?"

Some selfadjoint operators don't have eigenvalues at all.

Answer (score 3):

"Is it possible for zero to be in the spectrum but not an eigenvalue?"

Certainly. Let the Hilbert space be the sequence space $\ell^2$, and define $T$
by
$$T:(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots)\mapsto(2^{-1}a_1,2^{-2}a_2,\ldots,2^{-n}a_n,\ldots).$$
Then $2^{-n}$ are eigenvalues, and so as the spectrum is closed, $0$
is in the spectrum. But $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: Must this operator (compact self-adjoint injective on Hilbert space) have dense image?

Comment: Certainly this $T$ has dense image.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible that $0$ is not an eigenvalue, although it is certainly in the spectrum if $H$ is infinite-dimensional.  For example, on $\ell^2$ consider a multiplication operator
$$ (T x)_n = x_n/n$$

Comment: How to show that it is compact?

Comment: @CO2 : This operator is approximated in operator norm by finite rank operators, which are compact.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts finite rank means the image has finite dimension? So then it could be obtained by the maps cutting till $i$-th position? But with this proposition: $(Tx)_n=nx_n$ could be obtained also by the maps cutting till $i$-th position which all are of finite-rank. But I think I learnt this is not compact.

Comment: @CO2 : Look again. It's not multiplication by $n$, but by $1/n$.

Comment: The spectrum is closed, whereas the set of eigenvalues does not need to be closed. So, yes, $0$ can be in the spectrum and the operator can have only non-zero eigenvalues with $0$ as an accumulation point, for example.